# Trying to get divs to stay aligned in parent div

Tags: html, css

For some reason the `product-preview` don't want to stay vertically aligned inside `product-container` when containing the `product-preview-picture` and `product-preview-text`.

After looking over the text a bunch of times I can't figure out what it is that causes it.

```css
.product-container {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 2500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #232323 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-preview {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-preview-picture {
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
}

.product-preview-text {
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-preview">
    <img class="product-preview-picture" src="http://miniimg8.rightinthebox.com/images/384x384/201210/pldeyv1350894557095.jpg" alt="TRASIG BILD">
    <p class="product-preview-text">Best chewing gum ever!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to you're items.

```css
.product-container {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 2500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #232323 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-preview {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product-preview-picture {
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
}

.product-preview-text {
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- product display container -->

<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-preview">
    <img class="product-preview-picture" src="http://miniimg8.rightinthebox.com/images/384x384/201210/pldeyv1350894557095.jpg" alt="TRASIG BILD">
    <p class="product-preview-text">Best chewing gum ever!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align` on `.product-preview` to maintain its alignment

```css
.product-container {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 2500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #232323 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-preview {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.product-preview-picture {
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
}

.product-preview-text {
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-preview">
    <img class="product-preview-picture" src="http://miniimg8.rightinthebox.com/images/384x384/201210/pldeyv1350894557095.jpg" alt="TRASIG BILD">
    <p class="product-preview-text">Best chewing gum ever!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top` on your `.product-preview` preview selector

```css
.product-container {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 2500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #232323 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-preview {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-preview-picture {
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
}

.product-preview-text {
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-preview">
    <img class="product-preview-picture" src="http://miniimg8.rightinthebox.com/images/384x384/201210/pldeyv1350894557095.jpg" alt="TRASIG BILD">
    <p class="product-preview-text">Best chewing gum ever!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>

  <div class="product-preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.product-preview {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shifting of `.product-review` is caused by a `p` tag.

Try to put the `p` tag before the image.

It will shift the parent div so the `p` tag is on the one line with the end of the next `div`.

Unfortunately I can't find anything about that behavior of a `p` tag on the internet.

But you can neutralize it by adding `overflow: auto or hidden` to the parent (`.product-review`). If you will find some explanation please share.

```
.product-preview { overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Please, provide sample.